# Concurrency Check on an ICollection (during add)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET project, I'm using Entity Framework to set up one table that contains all `Project` objects, and another that keeps track of `ProjectMembers`. That is, a `Project` has an ICollection of `ProjectMembers`.

Each `ProjectMember` has a certain number in a `Project` that is different from the primary key (it can be thought of as a local id, a way to keep track of the count). Based on this number, a unique string is generated that allows each `ProjectMember` to be identified. It's important to keep these strings unique (no duplicates may occur).

**The problem**: When I try to add multiple `ProjectMembers` at the same time, I get multiple `ProjectMemebers` with the same string.

**Question**: Is there any way to ensure that no new `ProjectMemebers` have been added, or at least get some sort of error, when a new `ProjectMember` is added into a `Project` (preferably without using a lock statement)? Both Concurrency check and Timestamp don't seem to solve this issue.

---

**Project**

```
public class Project
{
...
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}
```

**ProjectMember**

```
public class ProjectMember
{
... 
}
```

This local id is generated by the following code:

```
projectMember.localId = project.projectMemebers.Count() + 1;
```

Comment: Why don't you use database generated identity instead of this?

Comment: @Kirill Bestemyanov, It won't work in this case since the table already has one identity column (for the primary key). The local id should auto-increment but it is only there to identify a project member given that we know the project, that is, it's a local id (a project member can have different local ids in different projects).

Comment: There is no restrictions on quantity of identity column in entityframework and mssql server.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov [Only one identity column can be created per table.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)