# Auto increment a column that is not an identity column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

In a project, I have set up a relation between `Project` and `ProjectMembers` such that a Project can have a list of ProjectMembers and ProjectMemebers can only participate in one project (see [Concurrency Check on an ICollection (during add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783974/concurrency-check-on-an-icollection-during-add)).

I would like to have a field that is auto-incremented, however, it shouldn't be an identity column.

For example, given a Project, once we add a new ProjectMemeber, that member will receive a number (like an id) that allows us to identify that ProjectMemeber only in that particular Project.

Is there any way to achieve this using EF?

Comment: Why can't it be an identity? That is what they do. If you are using 2012+ you could look at using a sequence.

Comment: When I add a new field  inside the ProjectMember (the local id) with the Identity attribute, then run migration, I get: "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'ProjectMembers'. Only one identity column per table is allowed."

Comment: So if you *already* have an `IDENTITY` column - what do you need *another* auto-incrementing value for??

Comment: I don't know anything about EF but in sql server you can have only 1 column with the identity property set to true per table. It sounds like something not setup correctly in the EF side of things to me.

Comment: @marc_s, it's because I would like to have a "local" id that allows us to identify a ProjectMember inside a certain project only. I.e. this works as if each Project has its own table of ProjectMemebers, even though there are only two tables.

Comment: Wouldn't you have a ProjectMembers table that would have something like ProjectID, MemberID, ProjectMemberID. In this case ProjectMemberID would be your identity column.

Comment: I think most of the time the best way would be to use an Identity field in your ProjectMember table like @aaron mentioned.  It sounds like you just want a separate field that starts over for each project, so for example project A would have ProjectMember 1 and 2.  Project B would also have ProjectMember 1 and 2.

Comment: @ Kevin H, That's correct! The "counter" should start over for each project. Do you think this can be achieved using some attribute in EF 6?

Comment: Why do you need to restart the values for each project? This value probably shouldn't be shown anywhere anyway.

Comment: @Sean Lange, I am using an algorithm to generate unique tokens that requires that one of the parameters is a unique number.

Comment: OK. Seems then to me that not starting over the counter would be better so that each value is unique. But you know your project so if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you can't use your ProjectMember tables' auto incrementing id.  Technically that is unique value for that member that you could use for your token.  Maybe there is a way but I don't know of a simple way to implement what you are asking for using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would have three entities - `Projects`, `Members`, and one used as a relationship proxy called `ProjectMembers`.

This third entity has only 3 fields - `id` used as the Identity with autoincrement, and `ProjectId` and `MemberId` as a ForeignKey relationship. Add a unique constraint such that MemberId must be unique (which enforces the one-to-one relationship on Members in Projects). The `id` will be unique to that member in that project. When they finish a project, that relationship proxy record is deleted, allowing reassignment to another project.