# Get a local index of an ICollection<T> in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

In my project, a `Project` contains an ICollection of `ProjectMembers`. Based on this, EF generates two tables, one for all projects and the second one for all project members. Is there any way to get a field that auto increments itself and that preserves the property that for Project-1, we would get project members with indexes 1 and 2, and for Project-2 we would get the same, i.e. project members with indexes 1 and 2?

---

**Project**

```
public class Project
{
...
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectMember> ProjectMembers { get; set; }
}
```

**ProjectMember**

```
public class ProjectMember
{
... 
}
```

This local id is generated by the following code:

```
projectMember.localId = project.projectMemebers.Count() + 1;
```

**What to achieve**: I want to have a field in the `ProjectMember` that can be auto-incremented so that for Project A it we would get the sequence: 1,2,3, etc. and for Project B, the same would happen, i.e. 1,2,3, etc.

Related questions:

- [Auto increment a column that is not an identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791746/auto-increment-a-column-that-is-not-an-identity-column)
- [Concurrency Check on an ICollection (during add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783974/concurrency-check-on-an-icollection-during-add?noredirect=1#comment51512535_31783974)

Comment: Take another stab at your question; it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, I've tried to reformulate the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814067/get-the-indexof-of-an-icollection-in-entity-framework