# Get the "indexOf" of an ICollection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two objects that are connected in a way such that `ObjectA` contains an `ICollection` of `ObjectB`. I would like to be able to determine the indexOf ObjectB in inside the `ICollection<ObjectB>` that is stored in `ObjectA`.

One of the solutions was to convert the ICollection to a list and then use the built in IndexOf. However,  when multiple threads access the ICollection, in many cases, I can get the same indexOf value for multiple ObjectBs.

**Question** Is there any way to have a certain field (of type int) that stores the index of ObjectB inside the ICollection? If not, is there anyway to ensure that indexOf (when multiple threads attempt to access it) gives the right index (i.e. no matter of the thread)?

**Possible solutions** I've tried to ensure to use a new context for each look up as well as `GetDatabaseValues()` and `Reload()`. This has worked better (especially in Debug mode), but when the debug mode is turned off, the same index of value is given to more `ObjectB`s.

---

### Edit

I tried to add an OrderBy statement, but it seems like none of the approaches work.

```
// var objectB  = new ObjectB();
using(var context = new ContextDb())
{
    var objectA = context.ObjectAs.Single(x => x.Id == 1);

    objectA.objectBs.Add(objectB);

    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Entry(objectB).Reload();
    context.Entry(objectA).Reload();


    var list = objectA.objectBs.Select(x => x.Id).OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); // order by primary key.
    sb.AppendLine( string.Join(",", list.ToArray())); // for testing
    objectB.LocalId= list.IndexOf(objectB.Id) + 1; // the "local id"

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The result is quite strange, although I seem to be able to see a pattern. Note, the code above is in a for loop that runs a certain amount of times. During the first iteration (first line in the string builder) gives the following:

`2932 2932,2933 2932,2933,2934 2932,2933,2934,2935,2936 2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938 2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940 2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940,2941,2942`

The second line:

`2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940,2941,2942,2943,2944,2945 2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940,2941,2942,2943,2944,2945,2946,2947`

The last line:

`2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940,2941,2942,2943,2944,2945,2946,2947,2948,2949,2950,2951,2952,2953,2954,2955,2956,2957,2958,2959,2960,2961,2962,2963,2964,2965,2966,2967,2968,2969,2970`

Does anyone know if there is a build in way in Entity framework to avoid these duplicates?

Comment: To answer your question, yes.  It's called a primary key.  I really can't think of even an edge case where the "index of" an entity object (inside of some in-memory collection) is meaningful.  This is the reason a primary key exists.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'm still not entirely clear on what you're looking for. However, there's a couple of things I can say based on your expanded question. First, when you pull *anything* from a database, there's no inherent order. By default, it'll generally be ordered by PK, if possible, or more appropriately by "insert order". However, that's risky to rely on if an exact order is necessary. If you need a truly exact and replicate-able order, then you need to issue an `ORDER BY` clause with the order you want.

Especially if you relying on navigation properties filled by Entity Framework through either eager or lazy-loading a foreign key, you can't rely on the implict order *at all*. Again, if order is important, then you need to use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` with some property on the entity to make sure that you get a true apples-to-apples order comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1. I tested the OrderBy approach, but there seems to be something wrong with the primary keys. In the database, they are all unique, but when they are retrieved by EF, I get duplicates that are not ordered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use IDictionary in which you can store index as well as the object.
IDictionary

Comment: would it be possible to auto increment the index in order to avoid duplicates?